# What exactly does "self" do in classes and methods

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python 'self' explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained)

Ok So programming in python, and just started using classes. Now is it that "self" keeps the information going instead of being passed or taken by the garbage collector?

I searched around and came to some... interesting things, but I'm not sure if I'm understanding it correctly though.

Comment: `self` is just the [standardized name] of the first parameter in a method. Python passes in the "receiver" (the object which has said method) on each method invocation as the first argument. The GC and object reachability is another issue entirely.

Comment: The listed "duplicate" does not address this question. Although, I am sure there are other duplicates.

Comment: It looks like an exact duplicate mainly because the title is poor.

Answer (score 3):

The `self` in Python is equivalent to the `this` pointer in C++ and the `this` reference in Java and C#.